# Why is mdadm shorting me 33 sectors on my linear virtual software raid device?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, gpt, mdadm

I am building a new computer system, with Windows 7 Professional and Ubuntu.  I am following this tutorial:

http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html

I want to be able to run my Windows 7 installation inside VirtualBox in Linux, but also to boot it from BIOS to take advantage of the full hardware if necessary.

So I'm having no problems up to when I'm trying to create the new partition table of the virtual disk created with `mdadm`.

If I run an `fdisk -l` I get this:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 078AFEF0-6B0F-443D-8572-3D6413D0FF63

Device             Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848     468991    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    468992  210184191 209715200  100G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 210184192  419899391 209715200  100G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 419899392  554117119 134217728   64G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 554117120  973547519 419430400  200G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 973547520 1000214527  26667008 12.7G Linux swap
```

I ran this to create my virtual disk:

`mdadm --build /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=4 /dev/loop0 /dev/nvme0n1p1 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme0n1p3`

But when I try to partition `/dev/md0` with `gdisk` my device ends at 210184158 not 210184191, being 33 sectors short. The EFI partition works fine, but the NTFS (main windows partition) won't read correctly when I use 210184158 as the ending sector.  Why is `mdadm` shorting me 33 sectors on my last device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fdisk` output contains the line:

> Disklabel type: gpt

GPT disks store a backup copy of the disk partition table and of the header at the very end of the disk. You can read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table):

> **16 KiB (by default) before the last logical sector of the disk**
>
> Secondary GPT table - It is byte-for-byte identical to the Primary table. Used mainly for recovery in case the primary partition table is damaged.
>
> **Last logical sector of the disk or Last 512 bytes**
>
> Secondary GPT Header - Contains the Unique Disk GUID, Location of the Secondary Partition Table, Number of possible entries in the partition table, CRC32 checksums of itself and the Secondary Partition Table, Location of the Primary GPT Header. This header can be used to recover GPT info in case the primary header is corrupted.

Since your sector size is 512 bytes, 16KiB + the last logical sector correspond to 33 sectors, exactly what you are missing.